# Altium designer - Keepout region with holes in it

Tags: altium, pcb-layers

I have a component which has a cavity on the bottom (the side that meets the top of the PCB).
How can I create a keep out region which spans the outline of the component, excluding the cavities?

[image: Illustration of keepout]

I tried using primitives for the outline shape and the cavities, marking them and using tools -> convert -> create region from selected primitives.
What happened was I only got a region that spanned the entire outer layer.

Any easy way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Can you draw it up from 4 separate rectangles or a polygon?

Comment: I think this article of the Altium documentation could help: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-track-keepout?version=21

Comment: @jeroen3 the cavities are not actually rectangles, otherwise that would be the solution I would have gone for.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for a polygon pour, hopefully you can use a similar strategy for your problem. You can achieve this with: Right Click > Place > Keepout > Track.

1. Draw your polygon pour.
2. Draw a keepout track for the outer perimeter of your desired keepout
   region **making sure it connects back to itself**. This will form a
   'keepout barrier' that will prevent the original polygon pour from
   filling the inside.
3. Draw a new polygon pour on the inside of your 'keepout barrier'.

[image: Keepout region with hole in it]